# Save a $_GET value because I use another one in PHP

Tags: php

Look at the code below and you will onderstand ;)

**Multiplecompetitions.php**

```
<p><a href="subscribe.php? Competition =1">competition 1!</a></p>
<p><a href="subscribe.php? Competition =2">competition 2!</a></p>
<p><a href="subscribe.php? Competition =3">competition 3!</a></p>
```

**Subscribe.php**

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['login']== "OK" ) { 
  $Competition = $_GET[' Competition '];
  echo $Competition;

  if (isset($_GET[' Competition '])) {}
?>

<a href="Subscribe.php?Subscribe=Character1">Subscribe </a>
<br/>
```

And more code…
As you can see, I will use another $_GET but I want to save the first one somewhere. How do I do this?
At the moment the first $_GET value gets overwritten by the new one.

Comment: I hope all those extra spaces are not on your code.

Comment: isn't it already saved in `$Competition`?

Comment: Take a minute and explain your issue thoroughly and clearly. Not everyone will see your question and "onderstand".

Comment: The spaces are just a mistake because I placed it in Word first :p
The issue is that I want to save the $_GET somewhere. People who understand $_GET will understand me I think.

Comment: We "understand `$_GET`". We *don't* understand what exactly you mean by "saving it somewhere" without more context. Sessions? Database? Files? URL?

Comment: Dagon understood me so no morep problems :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'guess' as to what you want:

use & and add as many  variables as you like to the url:

```
 ... <a href="Subscribe.php?Subscribe=Character1&Competition=3">Subscribe</a>...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You understood what I was trying to say :D I'll rep you as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

First, don't put spaces in the parameter name, it's not permitted. Also you should remove the space between $ and Competition (line 2).

You can have only 1 variable with the name Competition. When you get it, you store it in the $Competition variable, so you can later change $Competition without affecting $_GET['Competition']

Generally your question isn't very clear, please give more details